# Text element doesn't fit with div parent [Oxygen Builder / Wordpress]

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm building a wordpress blog with Oxygen Builder and I did other blogs with same features and I have had not problems fitting elements and doing it responsive (as oxygen is doing by himself)

So I have some problems fitting text element into a div. Other elements are fitting well and even being responsive but the "Text" element is overlapping the parent div (white box).

I've tried everything but nothing results, someone who has some experience with Oxygen Builder or any CSS rule to fix it?

I've tried to max-width the text-element to fit into the div but it doesn't look good and it struggles with other resolutions

[image]

Comment: Do you prefer to keep the popup width, or better, extend it to allow that text to fit well? If you share the link to the page so I can check its html, I can help.

Comment: I want to keep the "popup" width, page is infoerrores . com

Comment: ok, checking it out

Comment: Your problem is this ```#span-52-1836 {
    max-width: 70%;
}```